# How to convert lower case file path to actual

Tags: python, operating-system, sys

The variable `file_path` uses only the lowercase characters:

`file_path = '/users/username/documents/my_doc.txt'`

while the actual file path contains both: the upper and lower case characters:

`/Users/UserName/Documents/My_Doc.txt`

Interesting, that `os.path.exists(file_path)` returns `True` making me believe that I can ignore the letter-casing since Python and the OS the process is running on is not case sensative.
But the letter case becomes incredibly important if the file path starts with `/Volumes/` (why it is happening deserves a separate discussion).

How can we turn the all lower case file path to the the actual file path that correctly displays both the upper and lower cases?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: OS X in this case. But it would be great to have a solution for Windows and Linux as well.

Comment: Do `os.path.basename(file_path)` and `os.path.dirname(file_path)` return anything useful?

Comment: Sure, `os.path.basename` and `os.path.dirname` work as expected. You could try it yourself since I have posted the value of ` file_path = '/users/username/documents/my_doc.txt'`

Comment: Windows isn't case sensitive, so it won't matter there. The only way I know how to do it in a case sensitive OS is to use `os.listdir()` at each level and create a dictionary of lowercase foldernames and the matched foldernames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't, as it's not a deterministic mapping.  Instead, you search at each level for names whose lower-case version matches the one you have.

Note that the process may not yield a unique answer.  If you have both

```
/Users/UserName/Documents/My_Doc.txt
/Users/username/Documents/MY_DOC.txt
```

You can't tell which one was intended.

Also note that if an intermediate level contains multiple matches, you have to continue down *each* path to look for full matches.  For instance, if you have top-level `users`, `Users`, and `USERS`, you'll have to work with all three to see where the continuations might match.

If the file system is small enough that you can simply generate every file name and check them all, then that's the way to go: simple, easy to maintain, easy to follow.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but might still be useful

```
import os

def _case(folder, findme):
    items = os.listdir(folder)
    for item in items:
        if item.lower() == findme:
            output = os.path.join(folder, item)
            break
    return item

def casify_fullpath(file_path):
    output = r'C:\\'
    for part in file_path.split('\\')[:-1]:
        if not part: continue #skip blanks
        output = os.path.join(output, _case(output, part))

    return output
```

To run this, simply plug in your lower case file path

```
file_path = r'C:\Users\whoami\Documents\mY_dOc'
file_path = file_path.lower()
print("input", file_path)
print("output", casify_fullpath(file_path))
```